# Recover email account saved on iPhone

Tags: iphone, mail.app, password, keychain, gmail

Sorry if this is not the right place to post this question.
I've a Gmail account configured in my iPhone and I can send and receive emails. Problem is, I can't remember the password so I cannot login on my browser. I've tried to recover my account but no luck. I can't remember a possible password and any email account I add to be verified I get:

> Thank you for confirming that you can access the contact email address you provided.
>   Unfortunately, Google was unable to validate that ...@gmail.com belongs to them. Learn more about recovering your account.

Back when I've created this account I didn't add any phone nor a recover email.

Is is possible, some how, to discover the password saved on iPhone?

Comment: Have you tried looking in *Website & App Passwords* in settings?  As long as you can authenticate to the device and you saved the login/password, you should be able to see it.  If you didn’t save it, there’s nothing that can be done.

Comment: The email is used in Mail app. Unfortunately, when I add it,  there wasn't login via "Google Web oauth" so I didn't got asked if I wanted to save it in Websites & App Password. The iPhone keychain must have it right?

Comment: That’s the iphone keychain.  If its not there, well, it’s not there.  Unfortunately, it’s a lost cause